# Disable the outlining package in final mode

Tags: memoir, draft

I am using the *outlining* package to keep track of what I still need to write in my documents, but I would like it to produce output only in `draft` mode. The package comes with a `disable` option, but it ignores the global `draft` option.

Since I am using the *memoir* class, which conveniently defines the conditional `\ifdraftdoc`, a possible ugly hack is to put something like this in the preamble:

```
\ifdraftdoc
  \usepackage{outlining}
\else
  \usepackage[disable]{outlining}
\fi
```

However, I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution (aside from hacking the *outlining* package to support the `draft` option).

Comment: Why should that be ugly? I find this is a rather elegant solution. Only thing that could be considered more elegant would be `\unless\ifdraftdoc\PassOptionsToPackage{disable}{outlining}\fi\usepackage{outlining}` (it has only one `\usepackage` and doesn't load `outlining` inside of an `\if` construct, which is more stable).

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Precisely because I would rather not have multiple separate calls to `\usepackage` for the same package. You solution seems to be pretty much what I was after. Would you mind writing an answer, including a brief explanation of what `\unless` does exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to test whether you're in `draft` mode and if you aren't pass the `disable` option to the `outlining` package. This can be done with

```
\unless\ifdraftdoc
  \PassOptionsToPackage{disable}{outlining}
\fi
\usepackage{outlining}
```

The `\unless` primitive was added by eTeX and inverts the following TeX `\if`, so the result is pretty much the same as directly putting `\else` after `\ifdraftdoc` to negate it, but `\unless` is a bit faster.